# Animate element to its new position in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, dom

I have a container, with an unknown amount of cards in (ranging from 3 to 8).

```
|  --   --   --  |
| CARD CARD CARD |
|  --   --   --  |
```

And when one is clicked, all others disappear and the card clicked needs to move to the left. For example, if the middle card is clicked:

Cards disappear

```
|       --       |
|      CARD      |
|       --       |
```

Card moves to left (**with an animation**)

```
|  --            |
| CARD           |
|  --            |
```

The cards are able to disappear but I feel my solution isn't great. I cannot move the card to the left.

Here's my solution for the hiding of the cards:

```js
    cards.forEach(card => {
        card.addEventListener('click', () => {
            cards.forEach(card2 => {
                if(card2 != card){
                    card2.style.animation = 'fadeOut 0.2s linear forwards';
                }
            })
        })
    })
```

But I am very unsure how to move the card.
Here's the css for the card container and card itself.

```css
.cards{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
.card{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Is this possible with a css animation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Animate element to its new position

To animate an element to its new position follow this simple steps:

1. **Calculate the *current* X, Y** position of the element relative to the parent
2. **Hide the other elements** with `display: none`
3. Since the element has a new position now that the other elements are gone - snap **(move) it immediately back** where it was using CSS `translate: transform(x, y)` to the ***old* X and Y**.
4. **Animate** with CSS `transition` to **0, 0** `translate: transform(0, 0)`, which is the position this element actually occupies after the other elements were hided from the view.

Here's an example of the above list with an extra step to first fade-out the other elements before hiding them, and only than - animate the element:

```js
const animateCards = (card) => {
  const fxHide = `display: none;`;
  const fxFade = `transition: opacity 0.3s; opacity: 0;`;
  const fxMove = `transform: translate(${card.offsetLeft}px, ${card.offsetTop}px);`;
  const fxAnim = `transition: transform 0.5s; transform: translate(0, 0);`;
  let other; // Just to catch a sibling element as reference

  cards.forEach(el => {
    if (el === card) return;
    if (!other) other = el;
    el.addEventListener("transitionend", () => el.style.cssText += fxHide, {once: true});
    el.style.cssText += fxFade;
  });

  other.addEventListener("transitionend", () => {
    card.style.cssText += fxMove;
    setTimeout(() => card.style.cssText += fxAnim, 0);
  }, {once: true});
};

const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
cards.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', () => animateCards(el)));
```

```css
.cards {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.card {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
  <div class="card" style="background-color:#0bf;">1</div>
  <div class="card" style="background-color:#f0b;">2</div>
  <div class="card" style="background-color:#bf0;">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I get the error `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined` on the line with `other.addEventListener()`.

Comment: @Matt than make sure to use the exact same HTML markup classes that I used. The example above has clearly no such errors ;) - you don't need to use my exact code sample. Be creative, follow the above 4 steps and implement your own if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a pretty solid working solution:

```js
var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

function transitionOpacity(){ 
  cards.forEach( el => {
    if(el.id != this.id){
      el.classList.add("invisible"); 
    }
  });
}

function transitionWidth(){  
  cards.forEach( el => {
    if(el.classList.contains("invisible")){
      el.classList.add("thin"); 
    }
  });
}

cards.forEach( el => { 
  el.addEventListener("click", transitionOpacity);
  el.addEventListener("transitionend", transitionWidth);
});
```

```css
#main{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card{
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 2.5%;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.invisible{
  opacity: 0; 
}

.thin{
  width: 0; 
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id = "main">
  <div id = "1" class = "card"></div>
  <div id = "2" class = "card"></div>
  <div id = "3" class = "card"></div>
  <div id = "4" class = "card"></div>
</div>
```

Step 1: Add create html tags
Step 2: Create CSS
Step 3: Add all elements with card class to array
Step 4: Add event listener to all cards to listen for clicks.
Step 5: Add event listener to all cards to listen for the end of a transition
Step 6: Check ID of clicked element. Hide elements that weren't clicked
Step 7: Check classList of all cards that were made invisible and now make those cards shrink